# Facebook social plugin doesn't show

Tags: facebook

Every time I put a dynamic url in my facebook social plugin, the like buttons won't show or load.

This is what I did.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="{{$business->fb}}" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

I already load the script

```
   (function(d, s, id) {
              var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (d.getElementById(id)) return;

              js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;

              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9&appId=xxxxxxxxx";

              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

But the like and share buttons won't show and there are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this page. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1914581255449300/?hc_location=ufi

Seems like there's a global issue with the like and share button. Keep an eye on this page to see if it's fixed or not.

Regards,
Andrew

Comment: Hi yes thank you for the tip but the forum haven't solved the issue yet

Comment: Yes. I'm also waiting for them to fix it. But before jumping to any conclusion, I thought it would be helpful to name this known issue.

Comment: From what I've gathered and tested, all domain urls will work, for example google.com. But it wont work on facebook pages such as facebook.com/coca-cola

Comment: fortunately, the other day it worked and i used facebook pages but then right now something happened that it won't load the buttons.